# Make scrollable dynamic list of objects in Windows form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, list

I would like to make a simple Windows Form application which displays a list of persons. This list is dynamic (coming from a webservice).

For example, assume we have the class `Person` with the properties `id`, `age`, `name` and `email`. My code will make a request to my webservice and retrieve

```
List<Person> list = ...;
```

In my GUI, I would like to show the person in a table-like, scrollable structure (each row is a person). It is important to me that I can design the rows by myself and not use some boring basic list with text only. For example, there should be a contact button in every row in order to contact a person by its email. Or one column could contain a user image etc.

**Question**

What is the common way to do that? Would you use a table layout panel? Are there some good tutorials out there to show the workflow of my setup?

Is there a way to design one row in the Visual Studio Designer and dynamically generate the others from that pattern?

I would appreciate some tips.

Comment: Sounds like a datagrid to me. BTW, WPF is a much better choice if you can still switch!

Comment: The way I would do this is to make a custom `UserControl` to represent the list item and then create another *scrollable* `UserControl` to serve as the container.

Comment: Jesus Christ. Lol @ whoever voted to close this as "primarily opinion based".

Comment: First: thanks to you two for your hints! Second: What the hell, a downvote. I thought stackoverflow was a q&a platform to ask about professional programming techniques... I think there is no point of googling tutorials, because most people who post them are not very advanced neither; so I thought I could learn here from the best! ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a [`DataGridView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.forms.datagridview) is what you're looking for.  You can add buttons, checkboxes, ect... It is table like, and can be sorted if needed.